# draw line on form show/visible C++

Tags: c++, drawing, onpaint

Hey I want to draw something when a form pops up. I noticed the `OnPaint` even but it doesn't show my drawing. When I add it to a button it does show what I wanted to draw.

This is what I draw:

```
void TSelectElementForm::DrawLinesInLayout()
{
    EraseLayOut(); //draws a new square over the previous lines
    int X_origin, Y_origin;
    int X1, Y1, X2, Y2, X3, Y3, X4, Y4;
    int VectorSize;
    int scale;

    X_origin = Layout->Left +5;
    Y_origin = Layout->Top +5;

    Canvas->Pen->Color=clRed;
    Canvas->MoveTo(X_origin,Y_origin);
    Canvas->LineTo(X_origin,Y_origin+10);
    Canvas->MoveTo(X_origin,Y_origin);
    Canvas->LineTo(X_origin+10,Y_origin);

    VectorSize = ElementVector[Index].vectorLP.size();
    scale = CalculateScale();

    for(int i =0; i < VectorSize; i++)
    {
        int LPX = ElementVector[Index].vectorLP[i].X;
        int LPY = ElementVector[Index].vectorLP[i].Y;
        int BeginX = ElementVector[Index].el_beginX;

        Canvas->Pen->Color=clLime;

        X1 = X_origin + ((LPX  - BeginX) / scale);
        Y1 = Y_origin + (LPY / scale);

        if(i == 0)
        {  
            Canvas->MoveTo(X1, Y1);
        }
        else
        {
            Canvas->LineTo(X1, Y1);
        }
    }
}
```

So when I call this method in a button it works, but when I call this in a `OnShow` event or `OnPaint` event it doesn't draw anything.

The strange thing is, when I simply just create a new project with a `drawLine()` method(that draws 1 line) and a `OnPaint` event It DOES work. How is that possible?

So, simply 2 questions:

- Is this method to long to draw it before my form pops up?
- How can I get this drawn on my form right away when it pops up?

Comment: Few more detail would not hurt: for example which graphic framework are you using ?

Comment: Just on the form. I do use a Layout(Tshape) to give a coordination where it can draw (so it won't overlap text or something)

Comment: Does it make a difference if I'm using C++ in ubuntu or windows? never knew that. But yes I'm working with Windows 7, Embarcadero.

Comment: I think the onpaint is the right place where to call your DrawLinesInLayout() the problem is to inform your control that it needs redrawing and as far as I rememeber you do that with a call to .invalidate()